# Import csv file from html form using Python 3 cgi and DictReader

Tags: html, python-3.x, csv, cgi

This is my first post so please let me know if I do not follow protocol!

I am trying to use a HTML file dialog box to select and open a csv file and store it in a DictReader using Python 3. I succeeded using tkinter, but cannot seem to accomplish the same thing using cgi.

```
# Open file dialog box
in_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

# Read BOM into Dictionary
csvreader = csv.DictReader(open(in_path, "r"))

# Read Dictionary into string (stored in RAM)
data = list(csvreader)
```

I am able to view the entire FieldStorage using cgi.FieldStorage and form. My trouble comes in either trying to parse the full file path to open the file using open() or parsing the FieldStorage return value so it can fit into DictReader. FieldStorage also appears to change some \r\n to \r\n.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['fFile']
print(fileitem)


<form action='Import BOM Test.py' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<p><input type='file' name='fFile' id='file' /></p>
Project Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="fName" /> <br /> <br />   
Project Status: (R)eleased, (O)bsolete<br /> 
<input type="text" name="fStatus" /> <br /> <br />     
Project Revision: <br />
<input type="text" name="fRevision" /> <br /> <br />      
Project Variant Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="fVariant" /> <br /> <br />        
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Thanks for the time,
Keith